# Code breaking with a simple line

Tags: c#

```
var R = new List<CentroActual>();
var L = new List<CentroNuevo>();
string procedure = "EXEC [SEGM_CLIE].[SP_OBTENER_CLIENTES] '" +DocIdent+"','"+Cliente+"'";
foreach (DataRow DR in DBHelper.Workflow().ExecuteDataTable(procedure).Rows)       
{
    //pendiente
    R.Add(new CentroActual(DR["Contrato"].ToString(), DR["Solicitud"].ToString(), Convert.ToString(DR["Fecha"]), DR["Estatus"].ToString()));
    L.Add(new CentroNuevo(DR["itemNum"].ToString()));
} 
CambiarCentro(L);
return R;

public static void CambiarCentro(List<CentroNuevo> L) 
{
    //DO something
}
```

When i try to pass "itemNum" to List  L , the web service doesnt respond, if i comment that line, R is working perfectly.

I need R to be shown, and then with L i need to do something else... This is the CentroNuevo list class, just in case... The problem doesnt seem to be the list. But the passing of L to the method CambiarCentro

the little bugger is CambiarCentro(L);

```
public class CentroNuevo {
    public CentroNuevo() { }

    public string itemNum { get; set; }
    public CentroNuevo(string itemNum) {
        this.itemNum = itemNum;
        this.Load();
    }
    public CentroNuevo Load() {
        return this;

    }
```

Comment: I don't see any exception-handling.  Probably it is throwing some error and exiting.

Comment: Are you sure that procedure result contains "itemNum" column?

Comment: Please post a minimal, complete and verifiable sample as illustrated here http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: yep, there is a column "itemNum"